# Animating a sphere along coordinates? Blender/Python

Tags: python, animation, mesh

I'm extremely new to blender. I'm trying to animate a sphere along a path created in a csv. The idea being that once I manage this, I want to animate several spheres across a landscape.

I've found this snippet of code that theoretically should do it:

```
import bpy
import csv
from mathutils import Vector

csvPath = 'C:/ball_path.csv'

#Not the most efficient way of creating a mesh , but should be fine for just one object
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add
ball = bpy.context.object

startFrame = 1
increment = 5 #This can also be in the csv
newFrame = startFrame

with open(csvPath) as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        #First set the location and then insert key frame
        ball.location = Vector([float(r) for r in row])
        ball.keyframe_insert(data_path='location', frame = newFrame)
        newFrame += increment

#Set the end of animation, if needed
bpy.context.scene.frame_end = newFrame
```

The csv I've created has three columns and three rows, x,y,z I guess.

However, when I run it I get the following error in the blender python console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 43, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'location'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

Any help with the above, or an alternative solution to how to achieve the animation would be great.

Cheers.

Comment: Well, I can't see the object on the 3d viewpoint as I'm running all of the script together. I was guessing it was being created and animated all at once?

Comment: Scratch that, you just forgot the method call on line 8 : You need to add `()` after `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add`

Comment: Amazing, thank you!

Comment: FYI `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()` automatically creates a cube AND selects it in the viewport. this is why `bpy.context.object` points to this object after the operator is called